# No Android 7 upgrade for Nexus 6P?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, device-firmware, nexus-6p, 7.0-nougat, nexus-9

My tablet (Nexus 9) downloaded and installed the android nougat over the air about a month back. But not my phone (Nexus 6p). It just upgraded to another version of Android 6 yesterday. Is it expected or something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research and basically you need to
give it a few days, if that doesn't help try flashing it.
Here's a guide https://www.gottabemobile.com/2016/09/09/how-to-install-android-7-0-nougat-right-now/

Comment: +1, but a warning to OP: you will need an unlocked bootloader. If you haven't, unlocking it will wipe all your data. Using the `flash-all.sh` script also wipes your data. If you're not sure about diving into this then just wait for the staged rollout to come to you.

Comment: Thanks. I am not that eager to flash or mess with complicated stuffs like bootloading or jailbreaking. I can wait, but the question was merely out of curiosity. I thought if Nexus 9 gets the upgrade, then a 6P should get it sooner.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).